# Replace HTML content and revert on hover

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML table filled with short sentences in two colors.
I want to cover the text with bars of corresponding colors and, when each block is hovered, the content has to revert to its original HTML state.

I would like to do the following either with JS or CSS:

- leave the default HTML table as-is
- switch the original content via javascript to a sequence of ASCII 219 / &block / █
- make it switch to "original" content when each block (e.g. "last week tonight with J.Oliver) is hovered.

Any help with this method, or a more efficient method, is appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT / a similar code might do it for me, the only thing i miss is the "original content" word:

```
div:hover span {display:**ORIGINAL CONTENT**}
div:hover:before {content:"&block;&block;&block;&block;&block;"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a similar effect with just CSS - set the same color and background on the cells, then switch to something readable on hover:

```css
.red {
  color: red;
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
  background-color: blue;
}

.revealer:hover td {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="revealer">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="red">One</td>
      <td class="blue">Two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="red">Three</td>
      <td class="blue">Four</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: That is a smart way to do it, but I can't figure out a way to adapt it to a multicolored div!
See the first box, "last week tonight with J.Oliver": http://i.imgur.com/yBjJfMU.png

Comment: Instead of `td:hover`, you'd use something like `div:hover td { ... }`

Comment: Updated the example, revealing the whole table when the `div` is hovered.

Comment: That might work! I should only edit it so that "one" and "three" text color is red when hovered, and "two" and "four" is blue. I'll give it a try now!

Comment: Ok, that's it! I just had to edit the css:  
`.revealer:hover td {
  .blue.color: blue;
  .red.color: red;
  background-color: white;
}` thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you include jQuery, this will do what you originally requested:

```
$(function(){
$('td').each(function(idx){
    $(this).data().originaltext = $(this).text();
    $(this).html(fill_with_blocks($(this).data().originaltext));
})
$('td').hover(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).data().originaltext);
},
function(){
    $(this).html(fill_with_blocks($(this).data().originaltext));
});
});
function fill_with_blocks(str) {
    var blocks = '';
    for(var i = 0;i<str.length;i++){
        blocks += '&#9608;';
    }
    return blocks;
}
```